# How can I overcome the issue of output console disappearing after taking input or compiling in Visual Studio-2013 for C++?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am new to C++ coding and in Visual studio environment. My simple code to find a sqrt of a number is being compiled and even run but the console disappears after taking number as input and I am left with the debugging messages and final message of Program terminated with exit code 0. Basically no output is shown.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    double x{ 0.0 };

    std::cout << "Enter x-";
    std::cin >> x;

    if (x >= 0)
        std::cout << "\nSqrt(" << x << ") = " << std::sqrt(x) << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "\nWrong Value - cannot compute sqrt\n";
}
```

The code seems okay, it runs on online compilers. I have tried checking 'console' option from Linker->System->Sub-system->Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE). But nothing works.

There are also certain debugging messages that seem to be generated some of them I am showing below -

```
......
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\CtxGraphicsHelper.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\mmhook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\Sfrhook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wtsapi32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The thread 0x498 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x2500 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x30f0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\ShellHook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\windows.storage.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\SHCore.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\profapi.dll'. Symbols loaded.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\scardhook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\twnhook.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
'Project2.exe' (Win32): Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\System32\cxinjime.dll'. Cannot find or open the PDB file.
The program '[10912] Project2.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I tried checking the Tools->debugging->symbols->Microsoft Symbol Servers. Some PDF files were found and some were not. I want to get to the root of this issue and basically get my program to behave the way as its coded with output console taking input and showing the result.

Comment: That's because the console automatically closes after the program is done. If you run the program from cmd.exe you will see all output. Also there is a setting somewhere in Visual Studio to keep the console window open after your program finishes IIRC

Comment: Set a breakpoint (`F9`) on the closing `}` brace of `main`, then debugging (`F5`) will stop there before the program exits and the console closes. Then press `F5` one more time to continue and exit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can temporarily add a simple line at the end of code:

`system("pause");`

Don't forget to include: `#include <cstdlib>`